# Recommended way of scrolling on page load

Tags: flutter

In my application I have a couple of pages inside of a PageView. Each of them has got its own CustomScrollView that lets the used scroll what might end up being a long list of items generated in a SliverList. These lists are also stored in memory, so that as soon as they load there are several hundreds of items loaded.

Both pages are very similar and I would like to remember the scroll position of each so that I can return the user to where he left it. This is working nicely, after some trial an error, but I believe there must be a better and efficient way of implementing it.

Right now I just have a Future in initState that waits for a few milliseconds until the content of the SliverList loads (hopefully), and then scrolls down.

While this is the approach I've seen in other questions, I don't think this is reliable; it works, but if I reduce the time too much (e.g. Duration.zero), I'll get an exception because the ScrollController is not attached to any view or the scroll won't work as intended.

```dart
@override
void initState() {

  (...)

  _mainScrollController.addListener(onMainScrolled);

  Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 200), () {
    _mainScrollController.animateTo(
      widget.recalledScrollPosition,  // Offset passed by the parent
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    );
  });

  (...)

}
```

The method "onMainScrolled" just calls back the value back to the parent (where the PageView is) every time there is a change in the scroll position:

```
void onMainScrolled() {
  widget.notifyScrollPosition(_mainScrollController.offset);
}
```

I also tried another approach (unsuccesfully) with:

```
_mainScrollController = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: widget.recalledScrollPosition);
_mainScrollController.addListener(onMainScrolled);
```

But in this case, every time I return to the page, the scroll offset is a little bit lower and lower (the scroll has moved a little bit up, little by little, just a few pixels). So I'm not using this approach any more.

So, I'd like to understand what's the correct approach for this. Thanks.